# script failed to run docker-compose and ./asadmin start-domain domain1

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, glassfish, devops

**i try to do a simple script to run docker-compose and when container is running by docker-compose**

it should enter inside container and start glassfish with ./asadmin start-domain domain1

Script of running docker-compose & glassfish container

```
 #!/bin/sh
    
    docker-compose up -d
    
    docker exec -it glassfishapp bash -c 'cd glassfish5/bin && ./asadmin start-domain domain1'
```

when i run docker-compose and i enter into glassfish container with docker exec -it id bash

i can access to my application deploy into glassfish image
but when i use script i can't access

Comment: How would you do this task without Docker?  (Would you get a shell inside the application server process some how, or connect to it with a debugger?)  I suspect this is a task that needs to be run from a separate container or from the host.

Comment: Manually i run docker-compose and i should every time do docker exec -it (id of glassfish container) bash and i run the command : ./asadmin start-domain domain1 to run glassfish for that reason i do a script to do that the script will run docker-compose & access to container to run this command  ./asadmin start-domain domain1

Answer (score 1):

`docker-compose up -d` will fork into the background per the `-d` option, which means your script will immediately try to connect to a container which is almost certainly not started yet.